# SQL how to find message not responded to from DB

Tags: sql

I have created a database to stored messages sent from external staff (brokers) to internal staff(Bank A) and I would like to create a query that returns a list of all messages that haven't been responded too.

I have created the below query

```
Select COUNT(Message_Subject.MessageSubjectID), Message_Chain.MessageSubjectID
From Message_chain 
join Message_Subject on message_chain.messagesubjectid = Message_subject.messagesubjectid
Group by Message_chain.messagesubjectID
Having COUNT(Message_chain.messagesubjectID) = 1;
```

Which return only messages in the message chain which haven't been responded to as there are no more Messages with the same subject ID. However I wanted the query to show more data, like the message subject and the Message body but when I add this into my query I get an error message.

> Failed to execute query. Error: Column 'Message_chain.MessageBody' is
> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
> aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is the sql ...

```
Select COUNT(Message_Subject.MessageSubjectID), Message_Chain.MessageSubjectID, Message_Chain.MessageBody, Message_Subject.Subject
From Message_chain 
join Message_Subject on message_chain.messagesubjectid = Message_subject.messagesubjectid
Group by Message_chain.messagesubjectID
Having COUNT(Message_chain.messagesubjectID) = 1;
```

Can anyone tell me the best way to go about this please? I have attached an image of the tables from my db.
[image: ERD For my database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `having` clause is requiring only one row, so just use aggregation functions.  For instance:

```
select count(*), mc.MessageSubjectID,
       max(ms.brokerid) as brokerid
from Message_chain mc join
     Message_Subject ms
     on mc.messagesubjectid = ms.messagesubjectid
group by mc.messagesubjectID
having count(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to use aggregate functions to do achieve this :

```
SELECT
    COUNT(Message_Subject.MessageSubjectID)
    , MAX(Message_Chain.MessageSubjectID)
    , MAX(Message_Chain.MessageBody)
    , MAX(Message_Subject.Subject)
FROM
    Message_chain
    JOIN Message_Subject
        ON Message_Chain.messagesubjectid = Message_Subject.messagesubjectid
GROUP BY
    Message_Chain.messagesubjectID
HAVING
    COUNT(Message_Chain.messagesubjectID) = 1;
```

however here is another way of doing this :

```
SELECT
    Message_Chain.MessageSubjectID
    , Message_Chain.MessageBody
    , Message_Subject.Subject
FROM
    Message_Subject
    JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                Message_Chain.MessageBody
                , Message_Chain.MessageSubjectID
            FROM
                Message_Subject
            GROUP BY
                Message_Chain.messagesubjectID
            HAVING
                COUNT(Message_Chain.messagesubjectID) = 1
        ) msgchain
        ON msgchain.messagesubjectid = Message_Subject.messagesubjectid;
```